# Firestore, waiting for all files uploaded to storage before saving

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to save a document with attachments (one file and one image both saved in Storage) into Firestore. With just either the image or the file, I manage to save the document, adding the image in addOnCompleteListener. But when with both, I'm stuck.

This is how far I did:

```
//Create document to be saved

docRef = db.collection("messages").document();
docRef.set(message).addOnCompleteListener(task-> {
   if(task.isSuccessful() {

      //uploading image to Storage
      if(imageBytes != null {
        mStorageRef.child("image.jpg").putBytes(imageBytes)
            .addOnSuccessListener(taskUpload -> {
                taskUpload.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                    message.setPhotoUrl(uri.toString());
                    
                    //cannot add file upload here because if image is null, it will not be saved.

                });
            });


   }
 });
```

If I try to save the file after the image, then there is a problem because of it being asynchronous

**Update**
What I want to achieve is then:

1. Create Document Reference
2. Save Image and/or File to Firebase Storage
3. Attach the Image and/or File information to the Document
4. Save the Document Reference to Firestore

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your comment when you say "if image is null".  What exactly is null?  Also, it looks like you have a syntax error in your code.  Did you copy this directly from your app?

Comment: @DougStevenson Let's suppose the user doesn't upload a image, but just a file. I cannot put file upload inside Images' onCompleteListener